# 12 volt starter motor for reverse on a motorcycle with a sidecar

Tags: motorcycle, starting

I rigged a 12 volt gear reduction starter capable of turning over an 18to1 compression race car motor. it is a 4.4 to 1 gear reduction starter. I have two 12 volt battery's in the system for a total of 42 amp hours. It works perfectly while jacked up and not under a load. but it is an 800 lb. bike and the side car must weigh at least 250lbs. plus my weight of 180. The problem is as soon as I engage the starter it will back up about 5 feet and the starter disengages. any ideas to keep the starter from kicking out?

Comment: silly question as I'm not a motorcycle expert but can't you start it in neutral gear? or are you making an electric motorcycle?

Comment: (Next: Use a wiper motor for manoeuvring tight parking spaces.)

Comment: Please provide some details about the starter motor. It may have an overrunning clutch or other mechanism that provides a mechanical connection only until the load decreases, as would be the case for a starter for a gas/diesel engine.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Not sure why the motor would be driving the bike backwards? This sounds as though either you have the starter on backwards or it is wired incorrectly. You have two 12v batteries ... I take it you have these in parallel and not series? Amp hours are great, but what are the cold cranking amps? Again as was stated in comments, why can't you try and start the bike in neutral? Also, what are is the year/make/model/engine of the bike?

Comment: Also, please explain what you are trying to do here.  I believe you are trying to implement a REVERSE capability for your motorcycle using the starter motor to power it but clearly Paulster2 has a different understanding from what you wrote.

Comment: Is the sidecar there to contain the batteries>

Comment: The side car has two 20 amp batteries plus the motorcycle battery is also 20 amps for a total of around 60 amps. It doesn’t seem to make any difference if I use all three or just the two sidecar batteries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven’t provided any feedback to the comments, so I’m guessing that, lacking a reverse gear, you are trying to set something up to move your heavy bike backwards a short distance.

The starter is disengaging because your batteries are not sufficient for the task, so the battery voltage drops so low that the starter solenoid is unable to keep the starter’s gear extended against its internal spring force.

The wiring may also be too thin to carry the required current without excessive voltage drop.

Want proof? Use a clamp-on DC ammeter to measure the initial, peak amps that the starter draws when moving the bike. I’m guessing it’s several hundred amps.

Then, after recharging your batteries, connect them to a carbon pile battery tester. Crank the tester up to the amps that you measured before, and see how many seconds the batteries can produce that current at more than 10 volts. Less than 5 seconds. Probably less than 2 seconds.

When you have the bike jacked up, the starter experiences very little mechanical load, so it probably needs less than 50 amps to spin the wheel. Your batteries and wiring are sufficient for that. But when the bike is on the ground and you engage the starter, it is essentially in a “locked rotor” condition, and it will require many more amps.

I once measured the current draw on a starter that wouldn’t turn a little 1.9 liter diesel engine. (Unknown to me, a little crumb of carbon had fallen into a cylinder, and the piston was trying to squish it against the head, so the engine was essentially locked.) That starter was drawing 1100 amps from an 80 AH battery rated at 1050 CCA, 1200 CA. I stopped the test before any smoke appeared.

If you put a pair of 6 volt golf cart batteries (connected in series) into the sidecar, and if you wire them up with heavy welding cable, your starter will remain engaged for more than 5 seconds while you move the bike backwards. But if you keep moving under a load like that for much more than 5 seconds, the starter will start smoking. I don’t think you’ll get much life out of a starter used for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks MTA for your insight, you  understand what I am doing. It only has to back this heavy load 10 or 12 feet. maybe three seconds. I have tried three 22 amp hour batteries it didn't make any difference. I switched to 4guage battery cable didn't help. Some one also told me to try 24 volts since it only has to run the starter for 4 seconds at the most.  I am new to the site I hope I am doing this correctly. Bill

Comment: @Bill #4 ga wire is marginal, and I would only use it for a very short cable like 1 foot long. I'd say 0 ga (1/0) is better and 4/0 is ideal. Your question came from Electrical Engineering so I figured you're no stranger to clamp-on ammeters but if you're not going to measure current, borrow a fully charged, full-size car battery, bungee it onto the bike temporarily and use the shortest possible cables. This will prove that the system works, given enough battery capacity. Amp-hours are immaterial. You need cranking amps, and that can only come from a big, heavy battery.

Comment: Thanks MTA, I will pull one of the batteries out of my 6.7 diesel truck and try that. I have the room in the sidecar storage compartment for a monster battery, but I didn't want to add all that weight to an already heavy machine. the 4 gauge cables I have are only maybe 1.5 ' long. I tried 24 volts it seemed a little better but still the bendix kicked out.

Comment: Instead of pulling my truck battery I had an extra 300cca motorcycle battery. so now with the bike battery and two identical 300cca batteries in parallel I am up to approximately 900 cca. I tried it and only ran it for maybe two seconds and it went in that short period of time about 40 feet. I will never need to do more than that. It did not kick out the bendix drive. Also I felt the starter and all the wires and they were barely warm. So thanks MTA I think my problem is solved.  I am new to the site ,am I supposed to leave feedback?

Comment: @Bill Glad to hear it. Any time you see an answer anywhere in a Stack that you have joined under your username, you can upvote the answer if it is useful by clicking the triangle above the answer's score in the left margin. Any time **you** ask a question and one particular answer solves your problem or seems the best answer, you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark below the answer's score. For more info, take the tour here: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour